# my app needs to be shown in list of share with option

Tags: android

What I need to in order for my app to be shown in the list when user click on share option in any of tweeter apps.
For example, With the official tweeter app, if user clicks on share tweet option I want my app to be shown, so that they can share it with my app.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I did not use the proper keywords for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an intent filter to your manifest file registering your app as able to handle a sharing action intent:

```
<activity android:name=".YourAwesomeActivity">
<intent-filter
    android:label="Lorem ipsum">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```